# S3 AWS image Upload using Presigned URL from HttpPostedFileBase in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-upload

I am trying to upload image in **S3 AWS** from `HttpPostedFileBase`. I have a service API which provide [Presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) for image upload (upload uri). According to official AWS documentation for file upload has `fileStream` which take **filepath** as parameter. However, I do not have **file path** as I am using `HttpPostedFileBase` for save image directly to the AWS.

here is the code:

```
public void UploadImage(string requestId, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        var uploadInfo = GetImageUploadURL(image);

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(uploadInfo.Data.UploadUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
        using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8000];
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) //there is no filePath;
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

Is there any solution for use `FileStream` using `HttpPostedFileBase`?
Or there is different way of image upload on AWS using `HttpPostedFileBase` and Presigned URL?

Thanks